# Django url configuration error

Tags: django, url, url-routing, django-urls

so I have created a Django application with three html pages. I want from a page which is not the homepage to another. However, the there seems to be some mix up in the url when the server tries to access the latter page.

Here's my application urls.py:

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views
    urlpatterns = [

            url(r'^$',views.homepage,name='homepage'),
            url(r'^findnow.html/$',views.findnow,name='findnow'),
            url(r'^more.html/$',views.more,name='more')
    ]
```

I wish to go from "findnow.html" to "more.html". I want the url to be "localhost:port/more" but instead the server goes to "localhost:port/findnow.html/more.html".

Here's my html code snippet for findnow:

```
      <body>
        <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;text-align:center;"></div>
        <a href="more.html">MORE</a>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Here's my views.py:

```
    def more(request):
        return render(request,'myapp/more.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are linking `more.html` as a relative page.

You should either prepend a `/` to it:

```
<a href="/more.html">MORE</a>
```

Or reverse it using the `url` tag instead:

```
<a href="{% url 'more' %}">MORE</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

So adjust it to be:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [

        url(r'^$',views.homepage,name='homepage'),
        url(r'^findnow/$',views.findnow,name='findnow'),
        url(r'^more/$',views.more,name='more')
]
```

And your template:

```
      <body>
        <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;text-align:center;"></div>
        <a href="{% url 'more' %}">MORE</a>
  </body>
</html>
```